# Proxy? Port forward?

Tags: networking, configuration, proxy, nat, forwarding

So I'm looking for a simple solution in the form of a stand-alone middleman service to run on Ubuntu on a headless Raspberry Pi, listen on port 80 and forward the traffic from that, to and from an external IoT device on its own separate network which has its own internal web server.

The scenario is like this:

A dedicated Raspberry PI running Ubuntu 20.10.  It has an eth0 network at 192.168.*.* that is nothing but a reversing cable to the IoT device as the Pi and the device are sitting next to each other with no other network devices in play.  The PI also has a wlan0 network at 172.*.*.* and is running Apache but with alternate listening ports so that the default HTTP/HTTPS ports can be available for a pass-thru to the IoT box while pages can be served on the PI as well.

The IoT box is a turnkey device and I can't install any software on it.  It's got it's own web browser, accessible via port 80, and I don't know at the moment about the HTTPS port, which I'm thinking isn't an issue because both networks are private WRT the internet.   It's possible that the IoT device may require HTTP passwords to access its web pages, but as it's not exactly bleeding edge new, hopefully it'll work with basic auth or something that won't complicate things too much-- I don't really care if the connection is protected, since it's all private network behind a firewall to the internet.

What I want to do is to be able to browse from any computer on the 172.*.*.* local wifi, to the PI at port 80 and in doing so access the content from the IoT device's web server at port 80 on the 192.168.*.* network.  To a large extent, the point of the PI in the mix is to provide remote Wifi access to a IoT device that's only capable of wired ethernet.

Note that I'm NOT trying to pass-thru the entire set of ports from one network to another between the two interfaces, just what's necessary so that the IoT's web pages can be accessed as if they were served by the PI.

I've tried a bunch of stuff.  The PI was setup with netplan and ufw and both networks are accessible from the PI, and I can browse to the PI's Apache server via its alternate ports.  I can also browse to the IoT devices pages from the PI.  So both networks are up and accessible and I've opened up the relevant ports AFAIK with ufw.

I then tried to use ufw to do port forwarding and it appeared that would only forward a port on the PI to another port on the PI, which isn't what I'm after.  That's not completely clear to me but seemed to be how it behaved when I tried several example variations.  The problem there is, I see several example recipes of apparently similar configurations, but explanations of *how they work* seem to be lacking, so I've just been trying stuff without understanding what it's trying to do and then can't diagnose things or reason it out when it doesn't work.

I then found out about PortFusion which looked like a possible candidate.  It took me forever to get a version working-- the latest source 1.2.2 wouldn't build without error (it's in Haskell) though I finally found an earlier binary built for ARM (v1.2.1) that I was able to run, but couldn't get it to work and the documentation and examples are limited and it's essentially, abandonware with nowhere I can ask questions.  So I gave up on that.

I then discovered frp, which looked like another potential candidate, but seems to require a client and server portion, and since I can't install anything on the IoT device I'm trying to connect to, frp doesn't seem to be the right tool.

I also saw some mentions of using ssh to set up a tunnel but that seems to require SSH on the receiving end which isn't an option given I can't install anything on it.  Someone even suggested netcat for something similar, and maybe?  But how do I get it to be bidirectional?  It's not clear to me how the outgoing response from the IoT device should get passed through back to the external originator of the HTTP request.

This seems like it *should* be a VERY SIMPLE thing to do, but part of the problem is I really don't even know what is the right tool for this job-- port forwarding, NAT, tunneling, bridging, proxy, or some combination thereof.  And tools for all of those seem to be largely poorly documented, with examples that make unrelated assumptions than what I'm trying to do, or the tools themselves are simply designed to do something else.

And there are so many tools that are seemingly related that overlap, netplan, networkmanager, networkd, iptables, ufw, ssh, netcat, and all kinds of weird things can go wrong, especially if you start switching around among these various tools as some seem to interfere with each other.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, perhaps suggest what tool(s) I should be using to set up what kind of service(s), I'm kind of stuck at the moment, run out of leads.

Comment: Nginx or apache with proxy_pass should be enough, if you just want to forward HTTP/S from another server.

Comment: I looked at Nginx, but it seemed like overkill. I then spotted that Apache could do proxying, and research showed me that reverse proxy was what I needed. Before I got the chance to try it, I ended up turning off the firewall and suddenly, it was working and I found out that previous experiments using ufw was actually working but I must have had a port blocked. Disabling ufw left the rules in place, which I could see via iptables. So I ended up just using iptables-persist to insure that the rules will survive a reboot, and now I'm good. Iptables was enough to do it by itself, had I known how..

Comment: This is what I ended up with in ufw's before.rules:

`*nat`
`:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]`
 `-F`
 `-A POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE`
 `-A PREROUTING -p tcp -i wlan0 -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:80`
 `COMMIT`    (best I could figure out for code formatting here)

Comment: Good to know it worked for you, but most people would just put nginx there and let it direct traffic wherever.